# Expand TextView with animation to WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android

I'm implementing a ListView where the elements are expanded by clicking on them to show all the text. I'm using [this](http://android.leocardz.com/animated-expanding-listview/) implementation. 
As you can see that project was made considering hardcoded strings and one of the arguments is the height of the TextView after the expansion. Since I can't know the final height o the TV because my strings are fetched from the internet I set the expanded height to:

```
AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

As you may know WRAP_CONTENT to android is just a -2 Integer. My problem is that the -2 is passed to the animaton method which does the following calculation:

```
float height = (ToHeight - FromHeight) * interpolatedTime + FromHeight;
```

Because ToHeight is -2 (and assuming FromHeight is 200) the TextView animation height goes someting like this:

```
200.0
191.05173
175.801
158.36632
134.70096
105.341835
78.51846
53.146957
31.025742
9.73967
-1.203598
-2.0
```

So the animation gives the impression is closing but after that height gets just fine because is -2 (WRAP_CONTENT). How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to show some more code or your XML file that contains the `TextView` you're trying to animate. A solution that might work for you is to dynamically calculate the height your `TextView` should be when expanded. You can use `TextView.getLineCount()` to get the number of lines of text and multiply that with `TextView.getLineHeight()` to get the size, or at least something close, of how tall the `TextView` should expand out to.

In general, the `WRAP_CONTENT` constant is used as a flag for Android's framework to specify dimensions during layout.